# A method was called at an unexpected time at UWP Suspending

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, voip, windows-10-universal

While calling `SendMessageAsync` of `AppServiceConnection` on `Supending` of UWP application causing following error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'A method was called at
>   an unexpected time'

I am just trying to end the VOIP calls when suspending.

Comment: Did you already receive a TaskCanceled or ServiceClosed event? After that you won't be able to send messages anymore.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT yes, how can i inform the background thread that you need to end the VOIP call . I created a new AppServiceConnection but that also giving the same error.

Comment: I think we would need a lot more info about your app architecture in order to comment on that. There is not much content in this post.

Comment: We have uwp app for voip calls which uses appservice to communicate to c++ voip library via c++\cli.

Comment: Are you listening to the ServiceClosed event on the VOID side of the connection to end the VOIP call from there?

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT No, we are listening to requestreceived  on the VOIP side / background thread to get the   suspend event. As we are using extendedBackgroundTaskTime and never do deferal.complete() so that VOIP library always connected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188008/discussion-between-vikas-sardana-and-stefan-wick-msft).

Answer (score 0):

On the VOIP side of your AppServiceConnection, listen to the ServiceClosed event, which indicates that your foreground app that is hosting the AppService went away. At that point end the VOIP call from there.